# Subset a part of a string before a certain pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have *row.names* that look like this:

Input:

```
 S1_S2_S3_S9_AAACTGATFSRYB
 S3_S4_S12_S1_TTTTTTGATFSRYB
 S9_S4_S12_S1_S2_S19_S22_GTGTTTGATFSRYB
```

and I would like the following:

```
 S9_AAACTGATFSRYB
 S1_TTTTTTGATFSRYB
 S22_GTGTTTGATFSRYB
```

In other words I would like to retain only the last S* before letters start. 
I have totally 6000 rows

Can anyone help me please to write a *gsub* or something like that to extract the string I need?

Answer (score 5):

try this

```r
a =c(
"S1_S2_S3_S9_AAACTGATFSRYB",
"S3_S4_S12_S1_TTTTTTGATFSRYB",
"S9_S4_S12_S1_S2_S19_S22_GTGTTTGATFSRYB"
)


gsub("^.*_(.*_.+)$","\\1",a)
#> [1] "S9_AAACTGATFSRYB"   "S1_TTTTTTGATFSRYB"  "S22_GTGTTTGATFSRYB"
```

Created on 2018-07-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

---

Edit: add explanation on regex:

- `^.*_` matches string from the start(`^`) to the last underscore
- `(.*_.+)` matches string with an underscore, combining with the first part, it will match the last underscore and the surroundings, which is what we want.
- `()` and `\1`:

  > The backreference \N, where N = 1 ... 9, matches the substring previously matched by the Nth parenthesized subexpression of the regular expression.

Comment: `".*_(.*_)"` should do

Answer (score 1):

Non *regex* solution:

```
sapply(strsplit(a, "_"), function(i) paste(tail(i, n = 2), collapse = "_"))
# [1] "S9_AAACTGATFSRYB"   "S1_TTTTTTGATFSRYB"  "S22_GTGTTTGATFSRYB"
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative using regex and stringr

```
stringr::str_extract(a,"[^_]+_[^_]+$")
#[1] "S9_AAACTGATFSRYB"   "S1_TTTTTTGATFSRYB"  "S22_GTGTTTGATFSRYB"
```